# O que é Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, microsserviços

Pelo meu entendimento é uma ferramenta para gerenciamento de *containers* em aplicações que demandam variações no ambiente de produção. A partir disso, levantei as seguintes questões em relação ao uso da mesma em projetos.

- Qual o propósito e benefício do uso desta ferramenta?
- Ela é utilizada somente em [microserviços](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/271195/77268)?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Parte 1**

Em uma infraestrutura baseada em Docker, gerenciar um só servidor, ou 2 servidores é uma tarefa simples. Mas há cenários em que você tem centenas ou até milhares de servidores, e as decisões que precisam ser tomadas são:

- Mover container do servidor A para o servidor B
- Eliminar um container (e precisa descobrir em qual servidor ele está)
- Subir um conjunto de containers que precisam conversar entre sí e por isso precisam estar em uma rede lógica, mas não necessariamente no mesmo servidor.
- Há casos em que essas decisões precisam acontecer por conta de um host que caiu, não responde, está inoperante ou simplesmente falhou.

Todas essas dinâmicas são complexas e levam tempo para gerenciar.

Docker não resolve isso, mas resolve todo o resto que já sabemos.

Assim os orquestradores surgem como mecanismos que gerenciam toda a complexidade de entregar gerenciamento em larga escala. Eles entregam a capacidade de gerenciar muitos hosts sob uma perspectiva unificada de unidade de processamento, e isso muda completamente a forma como conseguimos escalar aplicações, isolar aplicações e gerenciar hardware ocioso.

**Parte 2**

Uma segunda característica, mais ligada ao conceito de **Cloud Native**, é a capacidade de extender o cluster de forma a permitir que você, após instalar alguns componentes, use yaml's extremamente simples para definir coisas complexas.

Esses componentes (chamados de operators) fazem o trabalho sujo de, com base nesse yaml simples, criar todos os recursos com a complexidade realmente necessária.

Você escreve 10 linhas de configuração, com uma semântica incrível,  expressando que quer um cluster de 10 nós de postgres e o *operator* se vira para gerar 300 linhas de configuração. Ainda vai esperar cada nó subir e configurar cada um deles, executando comandos de colocam o nó no cluster, com direito a serviço de backup ativo, periódico publicado no S3 ou Minio.

**Parte 3**

Diferente do docker ou docker swarm onde todos os containers são do mesmo tipo, no Kubernetes há uma separação entre tipos de componentes maior, com especificidades. Ingress Controller por exemplo, é um tipo de componente que se comporta como um proxy reverso. Já Ingress é uma estrutura de dados que server de configuração para o Ingress Controller. Em linhas gerais a configuração (Ingress) sensibiliza o componente (ingress controller), que se reconfigura para atender à nova demanda.

Diferente de outras alternativas, o Ingress é configuração agnóstica. Diversas implementações de Ingress Controllers existem, mas precisam saber lidar com esse formato. Isso é uma demonstração de como Kubernetes é desenhado para simplificar o processo.

No docker você teria de saber que tem uma demanda nova, gerar uma nova configuração específica para a implementação de proxy reverso que escolher, e recriar o container/serviço.

Answer (score 11):

De acordo com o próprio site do fabricante, `Kubernetes` é um sistema para automatizar a implantação, escalabilidade e gerenciamento de aplicações conteinerizadas.

> - Qual o propósito e benefício do uso desta ferramenta?

Com `Kubernetes` é possível:

- Executar diversos containers em diferentes máquinas;
- Escalar adicionado ou removendo containers de acordo com a mudança de demanda;
- Manter a armazenagem consistente com múltiplas instâncias da aplicação;
- Distribuir a carga entre os containers;
- Lançar novos containers em máquinas diferentes se algo falhar;

> - Ela é utilizada somente em microserviços?

Não, mas os benefícios são mais visíveis quando para uma aplicação com alta complexidade de implantação e manutenção. Qualquer aplicação que utilize containerização pode aplicar o `Kubernetes`, porém o ganho de produtividade pode não ser proporcional.

Answer (score 11):

## O que é o Kubernetes?

### **Preambulo**

As tecnologias de containers, como o [Docker](https://www.docker.com/), estão permitindo uma nova abordagem à maneira como os desenvolvedores criam e implantam aplicativos. Com containers, um desenvolvedor pode facilmente empacotar um aplicativo com todas os componentes necessários, incluindo bibliotecas e outras dependências, e enviá-lo como um único pacote, mas sem a sobrecarga de uma máquina virtual tradicional. Os containers e as ferramentas de desenvolvimento que os tornam fáceis de usar não são a história completa.

Para criar aplicativos complexos que exigem componentes diferentes, abrangendo vários containers em várias máquinas, você precisa de ferramentas para gerenciar e orquestrar seus containers. Uma ferramenta que está ajudando a resolver as necessidades de orquestração de aplicativos em container é o [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/).

### **O que é o Kubernetes?**

O [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/), em suma, é um sistema de código aberto para gerenciar clusters de containers. Para fazer isso, ele fornece ferramentas afim de implantar aplicativos, dimensionar esses aplicativos conforme necessário, gerenciar alterações em aplicativos containers existentes e ajuda em otimizar o uso do hardware subjacente abaixo de seus containers. O [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) foi projetado para ser extensível e tolerante a falhas, permitindo que os componentes do aplicativo sejam reiniciados e movidos entre os sistemas conforme necessário.

O Kubernetes em si não é uma ferramenta de plataforma como serviço ([PaaS](https://antonioricardo.org/2013/03/28/o-que-e-saas-iaas-e-paas-em-cloud-computing-conceitos-basicos/)), porém vai além de um framework básico, permitindo que os usuários escolham os tipos de estruturas de aplicativos, idiomas, ferramentas de monitoramento e registro e outras ferramentas de sua escolha. Dessa forma, o Kubernetes pode ser usado como base para uma [PaaS](https://antonioricardo.org/2013/03/28/o-que-e-saas-iaas-e-paas-em-cloud-computing-conceitos-basicos/) completa ser executada em cima. E é essa a arquitetura escolhida pelo projeto open source [OpenShift Origin](https://www.okd.io/) em sua última versão.

O projeto do [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/) é escrito na [linguagem de programação Go](http://www.golangbr.org/) e você pode navegar pelo [código-fonte](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes) no GitHub.

### **Quem escreveu o Kubernetes?**

O Kubernetes foi originalmente criado pelo Google, que vinha rodando sistemas semelhantes para gerenciar containers, como parte de sua infraestrutura interna, por muitos anos antes do anúncio do Kubernetes como um projeto de código aberto em 2014. Hoje, o Kubernetes é uma comunidade de código aberto em rápido crescimento com engenheiros do Google, Red Hat e muitas outras empresas contribuindo ativamente para o projeto.

Além disso, a Cloud Native Computing Foundation, um projeto da Linux Foundation, opera para fornecer um lar comum para o desenvolvimento do Kubernetes e outras aplicações que buscam oferecer soluções modernas de infraestrutura de aplicativos.

### **Como o Kubernetes funciona?**

A principal unidade de organização em Kubernetes é chamada de pod. Um pod é um grupo de  containers que são administrados como um grupo na mesma máquina ou máquina virtual, um nó, e são projetados para poderem se comunicar facilmente.

Esses pods podem ser organizados em um serviço, que é um grupo de pods que funcionam juntos e podem ser organizados com um sistema de rótulos, permitindo que metadados sobre objetos como pods sejam armazenados no Kubernetes.

Todas esses componentes podem ser orquestradas de maneira consistente e previsível por meio de uma API, por entre instruções predefinidas e por meio de um cliente de linha de comando.

---

> Para aprender mais assista a explicação [O Que é Kubernetes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mVL0nOM3AGo) no >Dicionário do Programador.
>
> Tradução e interpretação da página
> https://opensource.com/resources/what-is-kubernetes

Answer (score 10):

> Qual o propósito e benefício do uso desta ferramenta?

- Criação e implantação ágil de aplicativos: Maior facilidade e eficiência da criação de imagens de contêiner em comparação ao uso de imagens da VM.
  Desenvolvimento, integração e implementação contínuos: Proporciona criação e implantação confiável e freqüente de imagens de contêiner com reversões rápidas e fáceis (devido à imutabilidade da imagem).
- Separação de interesses Dev e Ops: Crie imagens de contêiner de aplicativo no momento da criação / liberação, em vez do tempo de implementação, desacoplando assim os aplicativos da infraestrutura.
  Observabilidade Não apenas visualiza informações e métricas no nível do sistema operacional, mas também a integridade do aplicativo e outros sinais.
  Consistência ambiental em desenvolvimento, testes e produção: executa o mesmo em um laptop como na nuvem.
- Portabilidade de distribuição de nuvem e SO: funciona no Ubuntu, RHEL, CoreOS, no Google, no Google Kubernetes Engine e em qualquer outro lugar.
  Gerenciamento centrado em aplicativo: Aumenta o nível de abstração de executar um sistema operacional em hardware virtual para executar um aplicativo em um sistema operacional usando recursos lógicos.
- Micro-serviços fracamente acoplados, distribuídos, elásticos e liberados: os aplicativos são divididos em partes menores e independentes e podem ser implantados e gerenciados dinamicamente - não uma pilha monolítica executada em uma grande máquina de propósito único.
- Isolamento de recursos: desempenho de aplicativo previsível.
- Utilização de recursos: alta eficiência e densidade.

Modo antigo e o novo modo(com Kubernetes)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Fonte: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/what-is-kubernetes/#why-do-i-need-kubernetes-and-what-can-it-do

---

> Ela é utilizada somente em microserviços?

Tambem pode ser usado em:

- [container-packaged](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container).
- [dynamically-scheduled](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/cmsc411/website/projects/dynamic/intro.html)
- microservices-oriented

Fonte: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes

Comment: Gostei do gráfico. Ele é importante para compreensão de como se dá a evolução do modelo tradicional para o modelo de desenvolvimento baseado e `Docker` e `Kubernetes`.

Comment: Link extras: https://aws.amazon.com/pt/eks/ e https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/services/kubernetes-service